# JS dividing by array

Tags: javascript, arrays, divide

Hello I recently came across a question where an array was fed into a function along with two other parameters(low & high). The question asked to divide the numbers from low to high by each value in the array and if all values were divisible to print the number and "all_match" and if only one or some were divisible to print the number and "one_match", otherwise just print the number. So I think the solution for an array with two numbers is as follows:

```
function dividedByArray(data,low,high) {
    for (i=low; i<=high; i++) {
        if (i % data[0] === 0 && i % data[1] === 0) {
            console.log(i + " all_match")
        } else if (i % data[0] === 0 || i % data[1] === 0) {
            console.log(i + " one_match")
        } else {
            console.log(i)
        }
    }
}

dividedByArray([2,3],5,10)
```

I have been trying to figure out how would you do this problem if you didn't know how long the array was (lets say the array was 4 numbers). I am relatively new to this. I have been trying out the map function but can't seem to figure out the way to do it. I also tried another for loop within the loop but it just printed everything twice. Thanks!

Comment: Loop over the array, which has a `length` property.

Comment: I don't have a computer in front of me to test this, but perhaps you could use a recursive function to solve this.

Comment: confused how to do that, how would i test if the value is divisible by every value in the array?

Comment: I need some clarification. 

let's say the call is `dividedByArray([2,3],5,10)`

What is dividing what?

Do they try to divide `low` and `high` by all of the numbers of the array?

Comment: Can you post a test function or two, that calls your function with data and tests if the results are correct.

Comment: we want to divide every value from low to high, inclusive, by each number in the array, 
if the number is divisible by all the numbers in the array we print "all_match"
if only by some we print "one_match"
and if by none of the numbers in the array just print the number

Comment: Hi Tinman I am not sure how to do the tests but if you paste that code into repl.it , it shows the result I want but I just want to be able to do it with any length of array since this would only work for arrays with 2 numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function dividedByArray(data,low,high) {
    for (i=low; i<=high; i++) {
       var passed = 0;
        for(var curr in data) {
           if(i % data[curr] === 0) {
             passed++;
           }
        }
        switch(passed) {
         case data.length :
              console.log(i + 'all_match');
              break;
         case 0 :
              console.log(i)
              break;
         default:
              console.log(i + " one_match");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow great thanks LanaStf, so the 2nd for loop cycles through all values in data and in the switch cases if passed equals the same length as the data we print all match, is that correct? Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's it. You must check every value so you assert full,partial or no match. Perhaps there is some faster way. You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use those Array functions, it makes code more readable. 
`every`, `some` and `filter`.

```js
function dividedByArray(data,low,high) {
  Array.from({length : high - low + 1}, (el,i) => low + i)
  .forEach(number=>{
    if(data.every(item=> item % number === 0))
      console.log(number, 'ALL MATCH');
    else if(!data.some(item=> item % number === 0))
      console.log(number, 'NO MATCHES');
    else
      console.log(number, 'MATCH :', data.filter(item=> item % number === 0));
  });
}

dividedByArray([5, 15, 10],5,10);
```